# Display first name using freemarker expression

Tags: freemarker

How do I display just the first name of the below string using freemarker expressions?

Name = Sam Jones

Required output: Sam

Comment: How do you want to identify the first name? Everything before the first space? You probably know [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [keep_before](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_keep_before), a Built-in for strings

```
${Name?keep_before(" ")}
```

> Removes the part of the string that starts with the given substring

You can check using https://try.freemarker.apache.org/, add in Data model field: Name=Sam Jones and the expression in Template field